# How to Place labels and give color range by number

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am now using D3 for my geo-graph chart.I am have coded to show map and color I have placed based on my csv file.

The html page is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

/* On mouse hover, lighten state color */
path:hover {
    fill-opacity: .7;
}

/* Style for Custom Tooltip */
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;           
    text-align: center;           
    width: 60px;                  
    height: 28px;                 
    padding: 2px;             
    font: 12px sans-serif;        
    background: white;   
    border: 0px;      
    border-radius: 8px;           
    pointer-events: none;         
}

/* Legend Font Style */
body {
    font: 11px sans-serif;
}

/* Legend Position Style */
.legend {
    position:absolute;
    left:800px;
    top:350px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">         
//Width and height of map
var width = 960;
var height = 500;   
// D3 Projection
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                   .translate([width/2, height/2])    
                   .scale([1000]);         

// Define path generator
var path = d3.geo.path()               
             .projection(projection);      

// Define linear scale for output
var color = d3.scale.linear()
              .range(["blue","red"]);

var legendText = ["Population Present", "Population Absent"]; 
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
var div = d3.select("body")
            .append("div")   
            .attr("class", "tooltip")               
            .style("opacity", 0);

// Load in my states data!
d3.csv("Population_education.csv", function(data) {
color.domain([0,1]); // setting the range of the input data
// Load GeoJSON data and merge with states data
d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {
// Loop through each state data value in the .csv file
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Grab State Name
    var dataState = data[i].SiteState;
    // Grab data value 
    if(data[i].Population> 0) {
    var dataValue = 1;
    } 
    else { var dataValue = 0;}
    // Find the corresponding state inside the GeoJSON
    for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++)  {
        var jsonState = json.features[j].properties.name;
        if (dataState == jsonState) {
        // Copy the data value into the JSON
        json.features[j].properties.MembersPresent = dataValue;
        // Stop looking through the JSON
        break;
        }

    }
}

// Bind the data to the SVG and create one path per GeoJSON feature
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("stroke", "#fff")
    .style("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
    // Get data value
    var value = d.properties.MembersPresent;
    if (value != undefined) {
    //If value exists…
    return color(value);
    } else {
    //If value is undefined…
    return "rgb(213,222,217)";
    }
});

// Map the cities I have lived in!
d3.csv("Population_education.csv", function(data) {
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        if (d.AvgLng != 0 && d.AvgLat != 0)
        return projection([d.AvgLng, d.AvgLat])[0];
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
    if (d.AvgLng != 0 && d.AvgLat != 0)
        return projection([d.AvgLng, d.AvgLat])[1];
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return 3;
    })
        .style("fill", "rgb(217,91,67)")    
        .style("opacity", 0.45) 
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
           .duration(200)      
           .style("opacity", .9);      
           div.text(d.place)
           .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
           .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
    })   
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        div.transition()        
           .duration(500)      
           .style("opacity", 0);   
    });
});  
var legend = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("class", "legend")
                .attr("width", 140)
                .attr("height", 200)
                .selectAll("g")
                .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

    legend.append("rect")
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .style("fill", color);

    legend.append("text")
          .data(legendText)
          .attr("x", 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Population_education.csv is below

```
RowID,SiteState,State Abbr,AvgLat,AvgLng,Population
1,Alabama,AL,32.806671,-86.79113,28
2,Arizona,AZ,33.729759,-111.431221,11704
3,California,CA,36.116203,-119.681564,4356448
4,Colorado,CO,39.059811,-105.311104,374435
5,Connecticut,CT,41.597782,-72.755371,455966
6,Florida,FL,27.766279,-81.68678300000001,442537
7,Georgia,GA,33.040619,-83.643074,1339081
8,Illinois,IL,40.349457,-88.986137,29
9,Indiana,IN,39.849426,-86.258278,1525124
10,Iowa,IA,42.011539,-93.210526,185146
11,Kansas,KS,38.5266,-96.72648599999999,129301
12,Kentucky,KY,37.66814,-84.670067,621047
13,Louisiana,LA,31.169546,-91.867805,170568
14,Maine,ME,44.693947,-69.381927,222966
15,Maryland,MD,39.063946,-76.80210099999999,256966
16,Massachusetts,MA,42.230171,-71.530106,27
17,Michigan,MI,43.326618,-84.536095,27
18,Minnesota,MN,45.694454,-93.900192,11
19,Missouri,MO,38.456085,-92.28836800000001,420415
20,Nevada,NV,38.313515,-117.055374,309799
21,New Hampshire,NH,43.452492,-71.563896,195948
22,New Jersey,NJ,40.298904,-74.521011,241039
23,New Mexico,NM,34.840515,-106.248482,1945
24,New York,NY,42.165726,-74.94805100000001,1075153
25,North Carolina,NC,35.630066,-79.80641900000001,14
26,Ohio,OH,40.388783,-82.764915,1526404
27,Oregon,OR,44.572021,-122.070938,11
28,Pennsylvania,PA,40.590752,-77.209755,197
29,South Carolina,SC,33.856892,-80.945007,45
30,Tennessee,TN,35.747845,-86.692345,446667
31,Texas,TX,31.054487,-97.563461,736672
32,Vermont,VA,37.769337,-78.169968,2324640
33,Washington,WA,47.400902,-121.490494,141319
34,West Virginia,WV,38.491226,-80.954453,128275
35,Wisconsin,WI,44.268543,-89.616508,405942
36,Alaska,AK,0,0,0
37,Arkansas,AR,0,0,0
38,Delaware,DE,0,0,0
39,District of Columbia,DC,0,0,0
40,Hawaii,HI,0,0,0
41,Idaho,ID,0,0,0
42,Mississippi,MS,0,0,0
43,Montana,MT,0,0,0
44,Nebraska,NE,0,0,0
45,North Dakota,ND,0,0,0
46,South Dakota,SD,0,0,0
47,Utah,UT,0,0,0
48,Virginia,VT,0,0,0
49,Wyoming,WY,0,0,0
50,Oklahoma,OK,0,0,0
51,Rhode Island,RI,0,0,0
```

My us-states.json is as in the following link [us-states.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alignedleft/d3-book/master/chapter_12/us-states.json)

Now I am trying to do two things

1. Place `State Abbr` and `Population` as a label in the middle of the state like in image I need to place code and population number

[image: Required sample]

and

2. color I am giving by two colors by checking `population > 0`. But I need to change like range(`fade from blue to red`) according to the Population number in CSV file

Comment: I'm working on it! On the tooltip you just want to fill it with the text, or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Just placed states names@TheBiro

Answer (score 0):

Before you start, you will need to update your `for` loop that arrange your `.json` file.

You need to deal with `State Abbr` and `Population`:

```
// Loop through each state data value in the .csv file
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Grab State Name
    var dataState = data[i].SiteState;
    var dataStateAbbr = data[i]["State Abbr"];

    // Get Population
    var dataPop = data[i].Population;

    // Grab data value 
    if(data[i].Members > 0) {
    var dataValue = 1;
    } 
    else { var dataValue = 0;}
    // Find the corresponding state inside the GeoJSON
    for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++)  {
        var jsonState = json.features[j].properties.name;
        if (dataState == jsonState) {
        // Copy the data value into the JSON
        json.features[j].properties.MembersPresent = dataValue;
        json.features[j].properties.pop = +dataPop;
        json.features[j].properties.abbr = dataStateAbbr;
        // Stop looking through the JSON
        break;
        }

    }
}
```

---

- Text

Updating: I updated the code to show the text on the map. You just need to `.append(text)`. Here's the code:

```
var text = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter().append("text")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            var centroid = path.centroid(d);
            return "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + centroid[1] + ")"
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")

text.append("tspan")
    .attr("dy", 0)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.properties.abbr;
    })

text.append("tspan")
    .attr("dy", "1.2em") // offest by 1.2 em
    .attr("x", 0)
    .text(function(d) {
        return  d.properties.pop;
    });
```

---

- Coloring

Just update your `color domain` with the min and max population values:

```
// Get Max and Min Population and update colorscale
var max = d3.max(json.features, function(d) { return d.properties.pop });
var min = d3.min(json.features, function(d) { return d.properties.pop })

color.domain([min, max]); // setting the range of the input data
```

And finally, inside your `svg.selectAll("path")` you just add the color according to state population:

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.properties.pop)
        });
```

---

Just notice that the population values are too much discrepant, and probably wrong, so the gradient coloring won't look very good.

Here's the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

/* On mouse hover, lighten state color */
path:hover {
    fill-opacity: .7;
}

/* Style for Custom Tooltip */
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;           
    text-align: center;           
    width: 60px;                  
    height: 28px;                 
    padding: 2px;             
    font: 12px sans-serif;        
    background: white;   
    border: 0px;      
    border-radius: 8px;           
    pointer-events: none;         
}

/* Legend Font Style */
body {
    font: 11px sans-serif;
}

/* Legend Position Style */
.legend {
    position:absolute;
    left:800px;
    top:350px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">         
//Width and height of map
var width = 960;
var height = 500;   
// D3 Projection
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                   .translate([width/2, height/2])    
                   .scale([1000]);         

// Define path generator
var path = d3.geo.path()               
             .projection(projection);      

// Define linear scale for output
var color = d3.scale.linear()
              .range(["blue","red"]);

var legendText = ["Population Present", "Population Absent"]; 
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
var div = d3.select("body")
            .append("div")   
            .attr("class", "tooltip")               
            .style("opacity", 0);

// Load in my states data!
d3.csv("Population_education.csv", function(data) {
// Load GeoJSON data and merge with states data
d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {

// Loop through each state data value in the .csv file
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Grab State Name
    var dataState = data[i].SiteState;
    var dataStateAbbr = data[i]["State Abbr"];

    // Get Population
    var dataPop = data[i].Population;

    // Grab data value 
    if(data[i].Members > 0) {
    var dataValue = 1;
    } 
    else { var dataValue = 0;}
    // Find the corresponding state inside the GeoJSON
    for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++)  {
        var jsonState = json.features[j].properties.name;
        if (dataState == jsonState) {
        // Copy the data value into the JSON
        json.features[j].properties.MembersPresent = dataValue;
        json.features[j].properties.pop = +dataPop;
        json.features[j].properties.abbr = dataStateAbbr;
        // Stop looking through the JSON
        break;
        }

    }
}

// Get Max and Min Population and update colorscale
var max = d3.max(json.features, function(d) { return d.properties.pop });
var min = d3.min(json.features, function(d) { return d.properties.pop })

color.domain([min, max]); // setting the range of the input data

// Bind the data to the SVG and create one path per GeoJSON feature
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("stroke", "#fff")
        .style("stroke-width", "1")       
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.properties.pop)
        });

var text = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter().append("text")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            var centroid = path.centroid(d);
            return "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + centroid[1] + ")"
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")

text.append("tspan")
    .attr("dy", 0)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.properties.abbr;
    })

text.append("tspan")
    .attr("dy", "1.2em") // offest by 1.2 em
    .attr("x", 0)
    .text(function(d) {
        return  d.properties.pop;
    });



// Map the cities I have lived in!
d3.csv("Population_education.csv", function(data) {

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        if (d.AvgLng != 0 && d.AvgLat != 0)
        return projection([d.AvgLng, d.AvgLat])[0];
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
    if (d.AvgLng != 0 && d.AvgLat != 0)
        return projection([d.AvgLng, d.AvgLat])[1];
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return 3;
    })
        .style("fill", "rgb(217,91,67)")    
        .style("opacity", 0.45) 
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
           .duration(200)      
           .style("opacity", .9);
           div.html("Tooltip div")
           .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
           .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
    })   
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        div.transition()        
           .duration(500)      
           .style("opacity", 0);   
    });
}); 



var legend = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("class", "legend")
                .attr("width", 140)
                .attr("height", 200)
                .selectAll("g")
                .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

    legend.append("rect")
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .style("fill", color);

    legend.append("text")
          .data(legendText)
          .attr("x", 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });
    });

});

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have updated the qustion. like in image shown I need to place `state abbr` and population number as u have given in tooltip

Comment: Ok, I'll try here. And about the coloring, everything correct?